# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() Error

Tags: wordpress, function

I am facing the following error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action()

here is my code

```
function testtheme_add_admin_page(){
     add_menu_page( 'testtheme custom options', 'testtheme', 'manage_options', 
'testtheme_theme_create_page', 'dashicons-admin-generic', 110 );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'testtheme_add_admin_page' );

function testtheme_theme_create_page(){
    //create custom options page
}
```

Comment: In plugin file? or in functions.php?

Comment: In functions.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call just your wp-load.php file first before any function execute.

Just call below line in top of your file and try again:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');
```

Where `dirname(__FILE__)` is point to the root WordPress directory, For example like **www.yourdomain.com/wordpress/**

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bro You have just not put the menu-slug over there

```
function testtheme_add_admin_page(){
add_menu_page( 'testtheme custom options', 'testtheme', 'manage_options', 
'testtheme',    
'testtheme_theme_create_page', 'dashicons-admin-generic', 110 );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'testtheme_add_admin_page' );

function testtheme_theme_create_page(){
 //create custom options page
echo "test";    
}
```